# How can I freeze a button once it gets to maximum position height on the page?

Tags: css, button, scroll

I have a button that starts out on the bottom of the page... When the user scrolls the button moves just like everything else, but I was wondering if there was a way to freeze the button when it's just below the header?

Comment: How does it moves? Javascipt? Could you show us the code that does it?

Comment: @JaimeGómez I think the OP is saying that it scrolls when the user scrolls as expected, but they want to capture the point at which it hits some screen position and then freeze it there.

Comment: Waypoint allows you to do that. See the [Sticky Element] http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/

Answer (score 0):

use this in your css

```
position: fixed; //it is stay on the bottom of your site even if you scroll down
bottom:10px;
right: 0px;
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to add a quick explanation to tie the code to the poster's question.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): *"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better"*.